# Pandas get_dummies in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert categorical variables into dummies using [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) in a `for` loop.
However, following code does not convert the dataframes.

```
data_cleaner = [data_train, data_val]
for df in data_cleaner:
    df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns = categorical_fields)

data_train.head() # Not changed
```

I know that an iterator in a for loop is just a temporary variable. But the modified code also didn't work.

```
for i in range(len(data_cleaner)):
    data_cleaner[i] = pd.get_dummies(data_cleaner[i], columns = categorical_fields)

data_train.head() # Still not changed
```

Anyone can help? Do I have to manually run `get_dummies` for each dataframe? FYI, Pandas `get_dummies` doesn't provide an `inplace` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run it as a list comprehension

`data_cleaner = [pd.get_dummies(df, columns=categorical_fields) for df in data_cleaner]`

or

`data_train_dum, data_val_dum = [pd.get_dummies(df, columns=categorical_fields) for df in [data_train, data_val]]`

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
data_cleaner = [data_train, data_val]
for i,df in enumerate(data_cleaner):
    data_cleaner[i] = pd.get_dummies(df, columns = categorical_fields)

data_train,data_val=data_cleaner
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works but a for loop does not?